# Getting ref to dom object to access it in React

Tags: reactjs, ref, gsap

I'm playing with components that live by themselves, with styling and interaction all within the component. I'm trying to run a tween on a certain mouse event, I'm just playing now so ignore the mess. I can set the state in order to get at a dom node ref later, but when I try to call a function to then tween that TweenLite thinks the node to tween is null.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Oh, and when I do specifically pass the ref in as a property when calling the function, the function runs as soon as the component loads.

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Stylesheet = require('react-style');

export default class Card extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //  Set state here if required.
        this.state = {Width: this.props.width, Height: this.props.height, cHeader:''};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //  This method is called when an instance of this component is created.
        console.log('New Card instance created.');
        this.setState({
            cHeader: this.refs.cardHeader
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div styles={[styles.card]}>
                <div ref="cardHeader" styles={[styles.cardHeader]} onClick={handleHeaderMouseEnter}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Card.propTypes = {width: React.PropTypes.number, height: React.PropTypes.number};
Card.defaultProps = {width: 350, height: 150};

function handleHeaderMouseEnter() {
    console.log("Did this run?");
    TweenLite.to(this.state.cHeader, 1, {css:{height:350}, ease:Power4.easeInOut});
}

var styles = Stylesheet.create({
    card: {
        overflow: 'hidden',
        width:350,
        height: 250,
        backgroundColor: '#E74C3C',
        borderRadius: 5,
        WebkitBoxShadow: "3px 3px 4px 1px rgba(196,196,196,1)",
        marginBottom: 25
    },
    cardHeader: {
        width: 350,
        height: 50,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 5,
        borderTopRightRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#3498DB'
    }
})
```

I've updated the code as shown below, still no joy. TweenLite is still struggling to find the DOM node.

```
export default class Card extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //  Set state here if required.
        this.state = {Width: this.props.width, Height: this.props.height, cHeader:''};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //  This method is called when an instance of this component is created.
        console.log('New Card instance created.');
        this.setState({
            cHeader: (this.refs.cardHeader)
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div styles={[styles.card]}>
                <div ref="cardHeader" styles={[styles.cardHeader]} onClick={this.handleHeaderMouseEnter}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    handleHeaderMouseEnter() {
        console.log("Did this run?");
        TweenLite.to(React.findDOMNode(this.state.cHeader), 1, {css:{height:350}, ease:Power4.easeInOut});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you case you call `handleHeaderMouseEnter` outside of class `Card`, in this function `this` refers to global scope (in browser it `window`), and in `window` there is not property `state` - it is `undefined`. You should bind `this` to this function

```
onClick={ handleHeaderMouseEnter.bind(this) }
```

also if you move `handleHeaderMouseEnter` to class you also need set `this` to this method,

```
onClick={ this.handleHeaderMouseEnter.bind(this) }
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/20742/)

Answer (score 1):

I think Tween expects a DOM node and you are passing a react component to it. Try this:

`TweenLite.to(React.findDOMNode(this.state.cHeader), 1, {css:{height:350}, ease:Power4.easeInOut});`

Comment: I assumed this would work also. I get the exact same error though. It cannot read the state of null. Not sure what is null, the instance of the class exists.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it:

```
<div ref="cardHeader" styles={[styles.cardHeader]} onClick={this.handleHeaderMouseEnter.bind(this)}></div>
```